# How to get larger item symbols for some lists in a Beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, fontsize, itemize

I am writing a Beamer presentation that mixes normal-size font for some slides, and large-size font for other slides.  When I use the `itemize` environment with a large font, the item symbol (a small ball) does not become larger, and the result is not aesthetically pleasant.

How can I make itemized lists with large item symbols, but only for those which have large text, not for the entire presentation (i.e., without globally changing the beamer template)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

itemize symbols have font size hardcoded in definition (look at beamerthemedefault.sty or beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty).

```
% Itemize items, circle

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{circle}{\small\raise0.5pt\hbox{\textbullet}}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{circle}{\footnotesize\raise0.5pt\hbox{\textbullet}}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{circle}{\footnotesize\raise0.5pt\hbox{\textbullet}}
```

Section 16.3 "Changing the Templates Used for Different Elements of a Presentation" form beamer manual explain how to change it. It seems that would be possible to define a template with an option for font size. I don't know how to do it but a fast solution could be redeclare itemize symbols with new hardcoded size, something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}[t]{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First item
        \item Second item
    \end{itemize}
    \bigskip
    {\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\Large\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Second first item
            \item Second second item
        \end{itemize}
    }
    \bigskip
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Third first item
        \item Third second item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Changing balls for Madrid Theme.

Madrid Theme (`beamerthemeMadrid.sty`) uses `\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}` which declares `\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]`. So we need to look for ball in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`. To do it short, in this file some 'spheres' are defined and used. You can make your own definition,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareradialshading[bg,parent.bg]{mysphere}{\pgfpoint{0.15cm}{0.15cm}}%
{color(0cm)=(bg!15);
 color(0.15cm)=(bg!75);
 color(0.3cm)=(bg!70!black);
 color(0.301cm)=(parent.bg)}

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{myball}%
{\raise-0.2cm\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{mysphere}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}[t]{Frame title}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item First item
   \begin{itemize}
     \item first subitem
     \item second subitem
   \end{itemize}
   \item Second item
  \end{itemize}
  \bigskip
{\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[myball]
  \begin{itemize}
   \item Third first item
   \item Third second item
   \end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

I think sphere sizes are related with font size because they are declared using ex units but I'm not able to change its size with just a fontsize declaration. May be somebody else can help us.

Comment: Thanks! But can you do the same with spheres (like in the Mardid theme)?

Comment: I edited my answer with a new partial solution for Madrid theme.

Comment: Thanks a million! The results still need a bit of fine-tuning, depending on usage, but this is a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the @Ignasi solution for change of the ball size is lacking in aliasing so the spheres have rough edges as you can see in the screenshot. To solve the problem, I modified the original definition in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty` by adding to preamble the following code:

```
% * original ball definition in beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
%\pgfdeclareradialshading[bg,parent.bg]{bigsphere}{\pgfpoint{-0.1849315ex} {.2260273ex}}%
%{%
%  color(0cm)=(bg!15);
%  color(0.1643835ex)=(bg!75);
%  color(0.3287671ex)=(bg!70!black);
%  color(0.4520547ex)=(bg!50!black);
%  color(0.53ex)=(parent.bg)}

% modified by 1.4x multiplication factor
\pgfdeclareradialshading[bg,parent.bg]{bigsphere}{\pgfpoint{-0.2589041ex}{0.3164382ex}}%
{%
color(0cm)=(bg!15);
color(0.2301369ex)=(bg!75);
color(0.4602739ex)=(bg!70!black);
color(0.6328766ex)=(bg!50!black);
color(0.742ex)=(parent.bg)}  

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{myball}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{bigsphere}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[myball]
```

Now all item bullet balls are 1.4 times bigger then in default template and they have smooth edges.

Answer (score 1):

If Big bullet is needed (spare or ball shape), a little modification on enumerating can do that

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Bullets}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  Item One
    \item  Item Two
    \item  Item Three
    \item  Item Four
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[.]
    \item  Item One
    \item  Item Two
    \item  Item Three
    \item  Item Four
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[....]
    \item  Item One
    \item  Item Two
    \item  Item Three
    \item  Item Four
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
    \item  Item One
    \item  Item Two
    \item  Item Three
    \item  Item Four
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and dirty hack, you could scale the sphere with the current font size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@usesphere#1#2{\hbox{\usebeamercolor{#1}\scalebox{0.1}{\scalebox{\f@size}{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{#2}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \end{itemize}
\bigskip
{\Huge
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Second first item
  \item Second second item
  \end{itemize}
}
\bigskip
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Third first item
  \item Third second item
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]