# Beamer: Change only several bullets in the list

Tags: beamer, itemize

I would like to change the bullets in the second `itemize` to arrows.

```
\begin{alertblock}{The Aim of this Research} 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 2-1
                \item Item 2-2
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize} 
\end{alertblock}
```

Form above, I would like to make:

```
・Item 1 
・Item 2
   => Item 2-1  (change bullet to arrow)
   => Item 2-2
```

I've tried inserting `\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\rightarrow$}` before and after the second `\begin{itemize}` and [the solution in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84940/95960), but they don't work.

Comment: Do you want to do this for all items at this level or for individual ones?  For individual items see [How to get larger item symbols for some lists in a Beamer presentation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23034) or [Change item symbol within itemize in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292898). For all items see [Change bullet style / formatting in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11168). One of these is probably a duplicate of your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define your bullet symbols direct in the itemization:

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item[$\rightarrow$] Item 1
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: This can become tedious if this should be done more than once. Did you test it, by the way?

Comment: Yes, but i think for two items it's ok.
Yes, I have tested it, should i post my MWE?

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to change the second level of *all* `itemize` lists, you can adjust the symbol associated with the `itemize subitem` template:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764

\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\rightarrow$}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}

  \begin{alertblock}{The Aim of this Research} 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item 1
      \item Item 2
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Item 2-1
          \item Item 2-2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize} 
  \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```